# Как поставить input внутрь функии

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу вызвать `input()` внутри функции. Я пыталась найти ответы в других источниках, но нашла только этот код

```
def example():
    while True:
        test4word = input("What's your name? ")

        try:
            test4num = int(input("From 1 to 7, how many hours do you play in your mobile?" ))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error! This is not a number. Try again.")
        else:
            print("Impressive, ", test4word, "! You spent", test4num*60, "minutes or", test4num*60*60, "seconds in your mobile!")
            break
example()
```

Но при запуске выдает ошибку:

> EOF when reading a line

Помогите решить проблему

Comment: А меня почему-то все нормально)

Comment: + у меня тоже все работает, каким редактором вы пользуетесь?

Answer (score 1):

Для меня ваш код работает правильно, нет никаких ошибок.

Ошибка **в коде**

> EOF when reading a line

бы просто значила, что вы что-то **начали** - `(`, `[`, `{`, `"` или `'`, но **не окончили** — отсутствует `)`, `]`, `}`, `"` или `'`.

---

*Но ваша проблема вероятно в другом*:

Вы запускаете программу — никаких ошибок нету (в противоречии с тем, что вы в своем вопросе писали), но ваш цикл *бесконечный*, он хочет имя, имя, имя, ...

В отчаянии нажимаете что-то как <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> и ваша программа кричит:

> Я хотела читать строку от пользователя, а напала на конец файла.

Для стандартного ввода нажатие <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> — в зависимости от операционной системы и окружения) генерирует *признак конца файла* (EOF — end of file).

Как это обойти, в моем другом ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали функцию, в которой бесконечный цикл с вызовом функции `input()`:

```
def example():
    while True:
        test4word = input("What's your name? ")
        # Продолжение функции ...
```

Когда вы вызовете эту функцию

```
example()
```

она будет бесконечно спрашивать имя (на английском).

Это не хорошо — надо дать пользователю *возможность каким-то образом сказать, что хватит,* он уже не хочет отвечать. Например так:

```
def example():
    while True:
        test4word = input("What's your name? ")
        if not test4word:                        # когда test4word пустым,
            break                                # выход из цикла «while True:»
        # Продолжение функции ...
```

Когда пользователь ничего не написал, только он нажал на клавишу <kbd>Enter</kbd>, бесконечный цикл прерывается.

Answer (score 0):

> EOF расшифровывается End OF File - Конец файла

Код правильный, но возможно вы случайно прервали операцию клавишами `ctrl + d` или `ctrl + c`

Попробуйте добавить в код пару строчек

```
def example():
    while True:
        test4word = input("What's your name? ")

        try:
            test4num = int(input("From 1 to 7, how many hours do you play in your mobile?" ))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error! This is not a number. Try again.")
        except EOFError:
            print('Ну зачем вы сделали мне EOF?')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('\nВы отменили операцию.')
        else:
            print("Impressive, ", test4word, "! You spent", test4num*60, "minutes or", test4num*60*60, "seconds in your mobile!")
            break
example()
```

[Пример взял с легендарной книги. Вот статья](https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/exceptions.html)

Comment: Пробовала этот код но получила ту же ошибку